# Can't access airflow web UI

Tags: airflow, webserver, airflow-webserver

My company has a linux vm specifically for Airflow.

- All the ports are opened in ufw
- Scheduler working: ok
- Webserver initializing: ok
- Postgresql configured: ok
- Company VPN access: connected
- command `airflow standalone`: working fine
- wget `IP:8080`: FOUND and the html is the Airflow UI
- I know the localhost is not 0.0.0.0:8080 but the machine's IP. (tried, not working)

The problem is when I try to access `Linux_IP:8080` from MY machine to reach Airflow UI. The error I get is ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (because it takes too long trying to connect).

How do I access this remote machine?

I had access once but it is no longer working and I don't know why.

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
8080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: This looks 100% like one of two things: 1) port is blocked for external connections by something 2) airflow is not bound to external port (not a network guy, but I know this from Rails. Binding to localhost:8080 is not the same as binding to 0.0.0.0:8080)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was related to some network problems. I could wget the page so it was running but could not expose it.

I just fixed the problem usind docker containers